# how to get permissions to create subprojects in this project teamcity

Tags: teamcity

Using Teamcity v2017.2.1 (build 50732). I am not able to create subproject in root (initial project), where one is already created. my user has SYSTEM_ADMIN role assigned. Don't know where I can get that permission.

Do anyone has experience such problem or its is that I can create subprojects?

Root

- Project1

I want to create Project2,

Root

- Project 1
- Project 2

Comment: Share the error message which you get during the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create subproject in Root project

**Step 1 :**

Go to `<your teamcity url>/admin/editProject.html?projectId=_Root`

**Step 2 :**

There is button called "**+ Create Subproject**", you can create sub projects by clicking on that.

**Note :** if you cannot open above url or button is not visible then please check your rights/permission.